# How to get a string out of $_POST that I can use in my php email script

Tags: php, string, email

I am receiving the error "$email must be valid and of type string" when i submit my html form via my website. I can echo the value to the screen after submit no probs but does not work in the context below, any ideas on how to fix this would be great

```
<?php

require_once('sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php');

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = (string)$_POST["email"]; 
$header = $_POST["header"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$from = new SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress($email, $name);
$subject = $header;
$to = new SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress("MY EMAIL", "MY NAME");
$content = new SendGrid\Mail\Content("text/plain", $message);
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = 'MY API KEY';
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

try {
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
    if($response->statusCode() == 202){
        echo "Email sent successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Email could not be sent";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} 

echo $response->statusCode();
var_dump($response->headers());
echo $response->body(); 

?>
```

Comment: `(null, "MY EMAIL")` what does `null` mean?

Comment: There is no `$email` variable in the above code, please post the piece of offending code.

Comment: I believe that's an argument for a persons name. Should I take it out?

Comment: according to https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/lib/mail/EmailAddress.php - first argument is address and 2nd is the name

Comment: Sorry I uploaded wrong copy, I have re-uploaded

Comment: I have swapped them round on my site and I still get the error @ Iłya Bursov

Comment: What does `var_dump($email);` show?

Comment: Nothing, I get a HTTP ERROR 500 on the site and my error log just states "$email must be valid and of type string"

Comment: Add `try/catch` to catch the `TypeError` that's being thrown so it doesn't kill the script, then you can see the output.

Comment: @Barmar sorry where should I add the try/catch?

Comment: Around all the code that calls `SendGrid` methods. You already have a `try/catch`, just move the `try` before the `$from` assignment.

Comment: Ah ok thanks will report back

Comment: Now I have "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method SendGrid\Mail\TypeException::errorMessage() in /home/al8xghxhnuw5/public_html/scripts/index.php:27"

Comment: OK so removing echo $response->statusCode();
var_dump($response->headers());
echo $response->body(); and changing errorMessage() to getMessage() now just displays "$email must be valid and of type string." when I hit submit

Comment: Do a print "Email is: " .print_r($mail, true); in the section where you are getting the message (getMessage()).  This should tell you what email is.  Or var_dump.

Comment: @NiteRain this correctly outputs the email address I typed into the Email input field. What does this tell me? The exception is still being thrown

Comment: Could you fill in this to a correct email format: 
$to = new SendGrid\Mail\EmailAddress("MY EMAIL", "MY NAME");  This isn't a valid email.